# Finding if a column is in a range

Tags: linux, awk, range

I have two files that I want to find out if a column of file1 is in a range of columns.

```
file1.txt
1 19
1 21
1 24
2 22
4 45

file2.txt
1 19 23 A
1 20 28 A
4 42 45 A
```

I am trying to see if the `1st column` of `file1.txt` is the same with `1st column` of `file2.txt`, whether the `second column` of `file1.txt` is in between `2nd and 3rd columns` of `file2.txt`, and append if it is in the range.

So the output should be :

```
output.txt

1 19 23 A 1 19
1 19 23 A 1 21
1 20 28 A 1 24
4 42 45 A 4 45
```

What I am trying is to find out if first columns are the same:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file1.txt file2.txt 

1 19 23 A
1 20 28 A
4 42 45 A
```

But I am not able to put the larger/ smaller conditions.
How do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may also help you here.

```
while read first second
do
  awk -v fir="$first" -v sec="$second" '$1==fir && ($2<=sec && $3>=sec){print $0,fir,sec}' file2
done < "file1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2;next} {split(a[$1],b);for(i in b) if(b[i]>=$2 && b[i]<=$3) print $0,$1,b[i]}' file1 file2
1 19 23 A 1 19
1 19 23 A 1 21
1 20 28 A 1 21
1 20 28 A 1 24
4 42 45 A 4 45
```

The first block statement stores the elements of file1 into the array `a`. The array index is the first column of the file and the array element is the concatenation of all numbers of the second column with the same number in the first column.

The second block statement loops over the the array `a` element with the same index as the first column and checks for the number in the array is in between the range.

---

Another approach is to use `join`:

```
$ join -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.1 2.2 file2 file1 | awk '$6 >= $2 && $6 <= $3'
1 19 23 A 1 19
1 19 23 A 1 21
1 20 28 A 1 21
1 20 28 A 1 24
4 42 45 A 4 45
```

`join -o` generated the expected output format. The `awk` statement is filtering 
the lines that are in range.

Answer (score 1):

Using join + awk:

```
join file2.txt file1.txt | awk '{if ($2 <= $5 && $5 <= $3) { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$1,$5 } }'
```

First two files are joined on the first column, then the columns are compared and output printed (with the first column printed twice, as join hides it).

Comment: `'$2 <= $5 && $5 <= $3 {print ...}'` is more idiomatic